# Return type overloading when implementing a Spark DStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, overloading, spark-streaming, data-science

currently trying to implement my own implementation of an ApacheSpark V2.0 DStream

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Time

class MQTTDStream[T](ssc: StreamingContext) extends DStream(ssc) {
  override def compute(validTime: Time): RDD[Int] = {     ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3), 1) }
}
```

The compiler in my eclipse environment is ok with that. But I'm pasting the code to a jupyter notebook in IBM DSExperience and get the following error:

> Name: Compile Error Message: :21: error: overriding method
>   compute in class DStream of type (validTime:
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.Time)Option[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Nothing]];
>   method compute has incompatible type
>            override def compute(validTime: Time): RDD[Int] = { ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3), 1) }
>                         ^ :20: error: class MQTTDStream needs to be abstract, since: it has 2 unimplemented members. /** As seen
>   from class MQTTDStream, the missing signatures are as follows.  *  For
>   convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.  */   def
>   dependencies: List[org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[_]] =
>   ???   def slideDuration: org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration = ???
>
> ```
>    class MQTTDStream[T](ssc: StreamingContext) extends DStream(ssc) {
>          ^ StackTrace:
> ```

EDIT: 31.8.16

Now I've progressed a bit:

```
abstract class MQTTDStream[T](ssc: StreamingContext) extends DStream(ssc) {
  override def compute(validTime: Time): Option[RDD[T]] =
    Some(ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3), 1))

  override def dependencies = Nil

  override def slideDuration = Seconds(1) // just an example
}
```

Gives me:

> type mismatch;  found   : Int(1)  required: T

Comment: `Option[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Nothing]];` Smells wrong. Are you sure all the dependencies are properly loaded in jupyter? With the same Spark version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are missing the type parameter for `DStream` (this is where `Nothing` in the error message comes from); 2. `compute` should return an `Option[RDD[Something]]`, not just `RDD[Something]`; 3. You also need to define `dependencies` and `slideDuration`.

So the least changes would be

```
class MQTTDStream[T](ssc: StreamingContext) extends DStream[Int](ssc) {
  override def compute(validTime: Time): Option[RDD[Int]] = 
    Some(ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3), 1))

  override def dependencies = Nil

  override def slideDuration = Seconds(1) // just an example
}
```

Comment: now I get:
overriding method compute in class DStream of type (validTime: org.apache.spark.streaming.Time)Option[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Nothing]];  method compute has incompatible type MQTTDStream.scala

Comment: Did you perhaps forget `DStream[Int]`?